# Is a c++ std::priority_queue the right structure for the dijkstra queue

Tags: c++, queue, dijkstra, fibonacci-heap

I don't think a c++ priority queue is the right structure for the dijkstra queue, because it contains no functionality for an easy lookup or deletion of elements.

The right structure would be a fibonacci heap, but there is none in the std library.

Does anyone have suggestions for a better, c++ implemented structure?

Comment: There is an implementation of a Fibonacci heap in [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost/heap/fibonacci_heap.html).

Comment: I totally recommend the Boost Fibonacci heap or the D_ary heap with D=2 (binary heap). Actually, this last use to be the faster when the grid is not big enough (which is in most applications)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::set` and store a pair<distance, vertex> in it. To lookup and delete elements, you can keep distance to each vertex in an array or in `std::vector` to obtain a pair<distance, vertex> for a given vertex quickly. The closest unvisited vertex is always in the first element of the set(and can obtained using `set.begin()`).

Comment: wouldn't be a hashmap better than a set in this case?

Comment: It is possible to find and delete minimum element in a set in O(log N) time but is not possible to do it in hashset or hashmap.

Answer (score 0):

For most practical purposes, the `std::priority_queue` based implementation is good enough for sparse graphs. Implementing Dijkstra this way has a runtime of `O(E log V)`. If you have a dense enough graph, you could simply use the basic `O(V*V)` version of Dijkstra's algorithm. As the graph gets denser, the asymptotics of the Fib-heap version move closer to the vanilla implementation.